# iMacro to generate random text or random number

Tags: random, imacros

I am using iMacros for quick static form filling and is there anyway I can generate and post random text using iMacros? For example can instead of `good boy` in the below iMacro for Google Search can I generate random text or random number and post it as content?

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com.au/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfq CONTENT=goodboy
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfb
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

random number from 1 to 10

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com.au/
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfq CONTENT={{!var1}}
```

Comment: How should I use this in my case?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. But is there anyway to generate random string for particular size?

Comment: there is no direct way, but you can use code above to take random letters from file changing !datasource_line with random number and adding it on to another.

Comment: Why not simply: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1);` ?

Answer (score 10):

You can generate a random string similar to the above solution with a slight modification. No need to read files or anything else if you simply want a random string with some specific length. It's a bit messy but it does the job

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 25)]}; string")
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you make text.csv file and in it place in column A text and in column B number ?

Then you can use this code.

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE text.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com.au/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfq CONTENT={{!COL0}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:{{!COL1}}
```

Comment: Awesome, will give a try.

Comment: Returns output as undefined.

Comment: This is usually because of something in CSV file. Check it.

Answer (score 2):

4 numbers

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*9999 + 1);")
```

4 characters

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z']; 
var string = ''; 
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 25)]}; 
string")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']; 
var string = ''; 
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 36)]}; 
string")
```